# JavaFx-8 - synchronisize two ScrollPanes

Tags: javafx-8

How can I synchronisize two or more ScrollPanes in JavaFx-8? No matter which scrollbar is moved, every SrollPane should be updated like the other.

I found a solution here, but it works only in one way:

[JavaFX ScrollPane - How to use one scrollbar to scroll 2 ScrollPanes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14895517/javafx-scrollpane-how-to-use-one-scrollbar-to-scroll-2-scrollpanes?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do bidirectional bindings for the `vvalue` and/or `hvalue` properties:

```
scrollPane1.hvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane2.hvalueProperty());
scrollPane1.hvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane3.hvalueProperty());

scrollPane1.vvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane2.vvalueProperty());
scrollPane1.vvalueProperty().bindBidirectional(scrollPane3.vvalueProperty());
```

Comment: I start liking javafx-8. Thank you.